# python, concurrent futures, does not work for the additional runs

Tags: python, multiprocessing

could someone help me with the following problem. I would appreciate it.

I am trying to run several processes in the same time. When I do it for the first time it works fine. However when I run it for the second time, it does not work properly. It waits some time and finishes in 5 minutes when it took 30 second to finish at the first time. When I look to resource monitoring I see that after the first run there are several processes "python 2.7" with zero to ten values (0 or 10) in CPU column. If i restart python and run code it works fine for the first time. After it again stops properly working. How could I set sustainable work?

```
import nltk
import concurrent.futures

def try_my_operation(k):
    sentences= nltk.sent_tokenize(k)
    return sentences

executor=concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()

futures = [executor.submit(try_my_operation, data['text'][i]) for i in range(0,data.shape[0])]
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

executor=concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(1)

executor.shutdown(wait=False)

gc.collect()
```

Comment: Is it possible that after the first run, your computer is still writing data to the harddisk in the background? In some systems this could happen even after the program has stopped (your operating system might be writing data from the filesystem cache). In that case, you could try waiting several minutes between the 2 runs and see if that improves the situation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did 10 minutes break between runs. However the same problem is still relevant. On the second run only one process takes 25%, the rest is zero. Although on the first run all processes took 100% of cpu.